# Can I use AWS CLI to create a dynamodb table in the local emulator?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, dynamo-local

Is there a way to use the following

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name TableName l --attribute-definitions AttributeName=Id,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=Id,KeyType=HASH --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5
```

to create the table on the local dynamo emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the `--endpoint-url` option.

Quoting from AWS CLI [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.CLI.html):

> The AWS CLI can interact with DynamoDB running on your computer. To
>   enable this, add the --endpoint-url parameter to each command:
>
> ```
> --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
> ```
>
> Here is an example, using the AWS CLI to list the tables in a local
>   database:
>
> ```
> aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
> ```
>
> If DynamoDB is using a port number other than the default (8000), you
>   will need to modify the --endpoint-url value accordingly.
>
> Note At this time, the AWS CLI cannot use the downloadable version of
>   DynamoDB as a default endpoint; therefore, you will need to specify
>   --endpoint-url with each CLI command.